# Shell script to take backup of any file in the current directory not working with multiple parameters

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to write a script which creates backup of any file parsed in as argument. But while giving multiple arguments I get an error as:

```
The file test newtest  does not exist
```

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILENAME=$@

copy_file() {
for i in `echo $FILENAME`
do
  echo " Copying files:"
  cp $i $i.backup
done
}

if ! [ -f "$FILENAME" ]; then
  echo "The file $FILENAME  does not exist";
else
  echo "The file $FILENAME exists. Copying file"
copy_file
fi
```

Scenario 1: (Working)

```
$ ./backup.sh test
The file test exists. Copying file
 Copying files:
$ ls -l test*
-rw-rw-r--. 1 osboxes osboxes 0 Jul 16 16:17 test
-rw-rw-r--. 1 osboxes osboxes 0 Jul 16 16:27 test.backup
```

Scenario 2: (Not Working)

```
$ ./backup.sh test newtest
The file test newtest  does not exist
$ ls -l test* newtest*
-rw-rw-r--. 1 osboxes osboxes 0 Jul 16 16:17 newtest
-rw-rw-r--. 1 osboxes osboxes 0 Jul 16 16:17 test
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can't test multiple filenames with `-f`, you have to do them one at a time. So put the loop outside the `copy_file` call.

```
#!/bin/bash

copy_file() {
    cp "$1" "$1.backup"
}

for FILENAME in "$@"
do
    if ! [ -f "$FILENAME" ]; then
        echo "The file $FILENAME  does not exist";
    else
        echo "The file $FILENAME exists. Copying file"
        copy_file "$FILENAME"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the fact that your approach would fail, if your script gets passed a filename containing space, your script contradicts itself: Inside `copy_file`, you assume that `FILENAME` contains a collection of file names (since you are going to loop over them), while further down, you do a `[ -f "$FILENAME" ]`, which means that you assume that `FILENAME` contains a single file name. You have to make up your mind, what the content of your variables are.

Now, how to fix it: Your seem to want to process a list of filenames, and if the file does not exist, issue an error message. If it exists, you want to make a backup copy, and write a message that you did so. Hence you need to loop over the arguments passed to your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename in "$@"
do
    cp -v "$filename" "$filename.backup"
done
```

Checking for existence is done by `cp` anyway, and printing meaningful messages when copying is done by the `-v`. Also, my proposed solution copes with spaces in filenames.

However, there is still a problem (which is also present in your original approach). Imagine that your script is called with the arguments `foo foo.backup`. Since the parameters are processed sequentially, `foo` will be copied over `foo.backup`, destorying the old backup file. After this, your script will create a `foo.backup.backup`, which will then just contain a second copy of the original `foo`. You have to think how to handle this situation.